# CakePHP : Updating all tables after user edit?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a CakePHP website, of which most of it works but I am trying to update the users page (which I redirect to for now, once I have it working I am planing on making it an AJAX update). Now the code does work,

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->loadmodel('Setting');
        $this->loadmodel('Address');

        if ( $this->User->save($this->request->data, $validate = true, $fieldList = array('firstname','surname','homephone','mobilephone','dob','gender')) ) {

            $NewUserID = $this->Auth->user('id');   
            $this->Session->write('Auth', $this->User->read(null,$NewUserID));

            $this->Session->setFlash('Update done :)', 'GoodFlashMsg', array(), 'Good');
            $this->redirect('/user');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry :( There has been an error, please try again', 'BadFlashMsg', array(), 'Bad');
            $this->redirect('/');
        } 
    } //End of POST
```

Now this does what its meant to, save the updated user details (Address is another table, of which I will do later). But when I re-load the User ID to refresh the Auth Sesssion information, the Address table information seems to be wiped from the Auth Session, as when it re-loads the page on the redirect the address information is blank?

I am just trying to update the Auth information (all of it, the Address Table is linked, via ID, to the User Table) when the user edits any of there information, be it user details or address details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the array format of user info stored in session before and after your `$this->Session->write('Auth', $this->User->read(null,$NewUserID));` statement using `debug($_SESSION)`. You will find that array format is not the same. So store info in expected format as your issue will be solved.

Also you should unset the password field before setting info to session.

Comment: Yes I sort have done that, I did a debug on '$this->Auth->user' before I run the save and then one after. The debug after, has remove the tables I had linked to it. I am just not sure how to re-build it, so that it does not remove the linked data?  Thanks.

Comment: Done it, many thanks, I looked into building it up and editing the information in different ways. So what I did, not sure if its right or not :( - was to only update the user information with '$this->Session->write('Auth.user', array ($this->User->read(null,$NewUserID)));'